# Difference Between Reset Done and reset Complete in Django 2.0 Authentication Views

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm looking at implementing user authentication to a Django project. I'm reading through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). It mostly seems straightforward, but there's one thing that I don't understand.

Apparently the authentication includes eight views:

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

When implementing a password reset I assume that what I want to do implement `accounts/password_reset/`, which forwards the user an email. Then, I need to implement `accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/`, which is where the user is directed to via the email. What I'm not clear on is what that should do when the user has updated their password successfully.

What's the difference between `accounts/reset/done/` (or `password_resest_complete`) and `accounts/password_reset/done/` (or `password_reset_done`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. This is how they look like:

```
class PasswordResetCompleteView(PasswordContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_complete.html'
    title = _('Password reset complete')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_url'] = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    return context

class PasswordResetDoneView(PasswordContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_done.html'
    title = _('Password reset sent')
```

The main difference is that `PasswordResetCompleteView` passes the `LOGIN_URL` to your template context.

Comment: That's the for `password_change_done` vs `password_reset_complete.` I'm trying to figure out the difference between `password_reset_done` vs `password_reset_complete`.

Comment: Thanks. It was the right idea. It pointed me in the right direction to figure it out!

Comment: @dahrens Do you know if its possible to have the reset views on the same URL? I dont like the fact that I end up with `password-reset/`, `password-reset/done/`, `password-reset/confirm/` and `password-reset/complete`. Instead if would like `password-reset/<key>/` with an optional key parameter. Also, you know why they decided to do it like this, instead of playing around with HTTP methods and request parameters in a single view?

Answer (score 5):

`password_reset_done` shows a success message when email is sent (after email is entered in `password_reset`). `password_reset_complete` shows a success message when password is successfully changed.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py) for these views, there is a comment explaining the process. Lines 237 - 242:

```
# 4 views for password reset:
# - password_reset sends the mail
# - password_reset_done shows a success message for the above
# - password_reset_confirm checks the link the user clicked and
#   prompts for a new password
# - password_reset_complete shows a success message for the above
```